# How to transform box-shadow from left to right

Tags: html, css

How can I make it so that the box-shadow transforms from left to right without adding the transform effect to the text itself.

This text will change sizes depending on the content so the box-shadow needs to be adjusted accordingly.

Currently my code looks like this.

```css
body {
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
 margin: 0px;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.container {
 display: block;
 width: 85%;
 /*center vertically & horizontally*/
 position:absolute; top:50%; left:50%;
    -webkit-transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
    -moz-transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
    -ms-transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
    transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
}


a, a:visited, a:hover {
 /*display: block; this makes the whole line justified*/
 -ms-text-align-last: justify;
    -moz-text-align-last: justify;
    text-align-last: justify;
 text-decoration: none;
    color: #000000;
 /*box-shadow: inset 0 -1.3vw 0 0 #00f9ff;  OLD SCRIPT*/
}    



#test1 {
    display: inline-block;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    visibility: visible;
    box-shadow: inset 0 -1.3vw 0 0 #00f9ff;

    font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 7.5vw;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 7.7vw;
    font-weight: bold;
    animation: stretchRight;
    -webkit-animation: stretchRight;  

    animation-duration: 1s;   
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;

    animation-timing-function: ease-out;    
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;    

    transform-origin: 0% 0%;
    -ms-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
}

@keyframes stretchRight {
    0% {
        transform: scaleX(0);

    }

    100% {
        transform: scaleX(1);
    }                           
}
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="container">
   <div id="test1"><a href="http://i.imgur.com/dqkgUe8.jpg">hello darkness my old</a></div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you explain more clear ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use `animation` and also the same `box-shadow` . Make a pseudo element with the same `width,height,box-shadow` as the `#test1` div. Also scale it to `0` at first, and then apply the animation to it.

Using `animation` instead of `transition` will let you activate the animation on page load, not on an event like `hover` `focus` etc. Which is what i think you want

see snippet below

```css
#test1 {
  display: inline-block;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  visibility: visible;
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 7.5vw;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 7.7vw;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: relative;
}

#test1:before {
  content: "";
  box-shadow: inset 0 -1.3vw 0 0 #00f9ff;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transform-origin: left;
  animation-name: stretchRight;
  animation-delay: 0.5s;
  animation-duration: 0.8s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  z-index:-1;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

@keyframes stretchRight {
  0% {
    transform: scaleX(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scaleX(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="test1">
    <a href="http://i.imgur.com/dqkgUe8.jpg">hello darkness my old</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @redongreen Glad i could help:D . if this was exactly what you wanted, do not forget to rate/accept my answer P.S. great song : the sound of silence ;)

Answer (score 6):

What you want to do is use a pseudo element that you can animate.
I've added the animation to the hover state for better testing

```css
body {
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
 margin: 0px;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.container {
 display: block;
 width: 85%;
 /*center vertically & horizontally*/
 position:absolute; top:50%; left:50%;
    -webkit-transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
    -moz-transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
    -ms-transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
    transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
}


a, a:visited, a:hover {
  position: relative;
 /*display: block; this makes the whole line justified*/
 -ms-text-align-last: justify;
    -moz-text-align-last: justify;
    text-align-last: justify;
 text-decoration: none;
    color: #000000;
}    




#test1 {
    display: inline-block;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    visibility: visible;

    font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 7.5vw;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 7.7vw;
    font-weight: bold;
}


#test1 a:after {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 3px;
  content: "";
  background: #00f9ff;
  transition: width .2s ease-in-out;
 }
 
 #test1 a:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
 }
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="container">
   <div id="test1"><a href="http://i.imgur.com/dqkgUe8.jpg">hello darkness my old</a></div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is the answer